Looking for A story Title of an apocalyptic story starring Mo Chujiu
I heard a story on YouTube where no title/author were credited. I am reaching out to see if anybody can identify this story as I would like to continue reading it.
The main characters name is Mo Chujiu. She is Chinese and died ten years into the apocalypse. She wakes up and gains a ring with a space ability. Using her ability and skills learned as a student in a military school she travels to Japan and then the US to collect supplies. She also gathers her team from her previous life and uses her knowledge to give them a good start on life, at the end of the world. Eventually, she gets a safe island and starts rescuing survivors, moving people out there.
If you know the name of the story, even if it’s not in English, please let me know.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=teHOHYG-yCg - It's a Chinese light novel that's been machine translated into English and given an AI voiceover. I'm guessing the poster has altered the names of the characters.
